# Protecting the admin routes using angular 6 and firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular6

I am working with Angular6 using Firebase. I am currently new to Angular. I am taking course of Mosh Hamedani from codewithmosh. But the problem is I'm using angular6 and the tutorial I'm watching in Angular4.

Now Im working with protecting admin routes. Where some credentials are define in firebase.

I have to work with show and hide features if the user is admin.

Here is the data define about the user in firebase.

[image]

admin-auth-guard.service.ts

Here is the error while working on this amdin-auth file.

[image]

auth.service.ts

[image]

user.service.ts

[image]

app-user.ts

[image]

Comment: "Here is the error while working on this amdin-auth file"  what is the error ?

Comment: @xrobert35 ERROR in src/app/admin-auth-guard.service.ts(18,14): error TS2345: Argument of type '(user: User) => AngularFireObject<AppUser>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: User, index: number) => ObservableInput<{}>'.
  Type 'AngularFireObject<AppUser>' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'.
    Type 'AngularFireObject<AppUser>' is not assignable to type 'Iterable<{}>'.
      Property '[Symbol.iterator]' is missing in type 'AngularFireObject<AppUser>'.
src/app/admin-auth-guard.service.ts(21,27): error TS2339: Property 'isAdmin' does not exist on type '{}'.

Comment: Have you fixed your issue?? if yes.
could you please post your solution??

Comment: I'm also facing the same problem. I use angular 8, Firebase 6.6.2 & rxjs 6.4.0. Since i'm using rxjs latest version, i used switchMap inside the pipe. But i got the below error in the response. **Argument of type '(user: User) => AngularFireObject<AppUser>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: User, index: number) => ObservableInput<any>'.**

Answer (score 2):

The changes you have made in user.service.ts for still using angular realtime db is ok, you just need to change your canActivate method...
the userService.get(user.uid) returns angularfireobject and you need to convert that to observable by calling .valueChanges(). Thats all.

```
canActivate() : Observable<boolean>{
      return this.auth.user$
        .switchMap( user => { 
                return this.userService.get(user.uid).valueChanges();
              } )
              .map( appUser => appUser.isAdmin);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you showed the error instead of highlighting as you did. Anyways, for routes guards, this is how I achieve it.

in **auth.service.ts**

```
export class AuthService {
  user$: Observable<AppUser>;
  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private db: AngularFireDatabase) 
 {
     this.user$ = this.afAuth.authState
      .pipe(switchMap(user_ => {
        if (user_) {
          return this.db.object(`users/${user_.uid}`).valueChanges();
        } else {
          return of(null);
        }
      }));
 }
}
```

This way whenever you subscribe user$ observable you'll always have the user's object from Real time database.

Afterwards, in **admin-auth-guard.service.ts**:

```
constructor(private _auth: AuthService,
              private _router: Router) {
  }

canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | 
    Promise<boolean> | boolean {

    return this._auth.user$.pipe(
      take(1),
      map(user => user && user.admin),
      tap(isAdmin => {
        if (!isAdmin) {
          console.error('Access denied - Admins only');
// re-route to wherever you want 
          this.router.navigate(['login']); 
        }
      })
    );

  }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: sorry it didn't work show i've planned just to improve in aadmin-auth-guard.service.ts file following error show in command line: ERROR in src/app/admin-auth-guard.service.ts(24,29): error TS2339: Property 'isAdmin' does not exist on type 'User'. Above is the code i will be thankful to you if you help me to find out this error and help me to solve this problem

Comment: oh, i just found it. in you admingaurd inside the switchmap you have to do this: "return this.userService.get(user.uid). valueChanges ()"

Comment: still not working riazosama. Still i get the highlighting error on the line switchMap(user => {})// here is the error //  & at the end map(appUser => appUser.isAdmin) // here at isAdmin is highlighting //. For reference you may check the above screenshot of file admin-auth-guard.service.ts file where I've marked the issue. Everything is running perfectly but only in this file I'm getting error.

Comment: When I put cursor in the switchMap(user // here => { .. }) in VS code it shows like this [ts]
Argument of type '(user: User) => AngularFireObject<AppUser>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: User, index: number) => ObservableInput<{}>'.
  Type 'AngularFireObject<AppUser>' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'.
    Type 'AngularFireObject<AppUser>' is not assignable to type 'Iterable<{}>'.
      Property '[Symbol.iterator]' is missing in type 'AngularFireObject<AppUser>'.
function(user: firebase.User): AngularFireObject<AppUser>

Comment: did you try adding valueChanges() as mentioned in my last comment?

Comment: and when i put cursor in the map(appUser => appUser.isAdmin) here at isAdmin it shows like this  [ts] Property 'isAdmin' does not exist on type '{}'.
any

Comment: yes it's working no errors now valueChanges() works. But when i checked in browser  and click in some link where I've define AdminAuthGuard it didn't work I didn't see any action performed. { path: 'admin/products', component: AdminProductsComponent, canActivate: [ AuthGuard, AdminAuthGuard ] },
{ path: 'admin/orders', component: AdminOrdersComponent, canActivate: [ AuthGuard, AdminAuthGuard ] },

Comment: there is no logs in console and as well as in cmd. But the links are not working when i try to click. No action but it's show correct link but the page is not accessing other's links are working perfectly for anonymous user. There is two link I sent you the code which have to accessible when s/he is admin. If the isAdmin: false in firebase it shouldn't work. Currently nothing is work. No logs, ni errors but not able to access those links.

Comment: your solution helps me a lot to achieve this.
thanks riazosama

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just Typescript compile-time checking if you run the application and test it to see the error on the console it'd be better,however to fix this issue you need to annotate appUser with AppUser interface, like this:

```
 canActivate() {
    return this.afService.user$.pipe(
      switchMap(result => this.userService.get(result.uid)),
      map((userApp: AppUser) => userApp.isAdmin)
    );
  }
```

I've also got ride of the return key word along with braces as they're useless since it just one line arrow function, so this code is equal

```
switchMap(result => this.userService.get(result.uid))
```

to this code

```
switchMap(result => {
   return this.userService.get(result.uid)
})
```

yet I'm not quite sure why (user) in switchMap highlighted, if you post the error message I might be able to help, if the previous answer didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I've modified your method and see if it works

First add the method as below in auth.service.ts after logout() method

```
get appUser$() : Observable<AppUser> {
      return this.user$.pipe(switchMap(user => {
        if (user) return this.userService.get(user.uid).valueChanges();

        return of(null); 
      }))
}
```

and then make changes in canActivate() method

```
canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.afService.appUser$
    .pipe(map (appUser => appUser.isAdmin));
}
```

Just watch out my project on Github [My Github Link](https://github.com/Pranav50/E-Commerce) which is built in Angular 7. Your Angular 6 project will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

What must canActivate return? An `Observable`, right?

But, You return an `AngularFireObject` which is not an Observable.

So, in your **user.service.ts** file, Use `valueChanges()` method which will return an `Observable`.

```
get(uid: string): Observable<AppUser> {
  return this.db.object<AppUser>('/users/' + uid).valueChanges();
}
```

And in your **admin-auth-guard.service.ts** file,

```
canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.afService.user$.pipe(
    switchMap(({uid}) => this.userService.get(uid)),
    map(user => user.isAdmin)
  );
}
```

**To understand better:**
https://forum.codewithmosh.com/d/1210-oshop-protecting-admin-routes-not-able-to-get-uid-from-firebase/20

Comment: It works fine with angular 8, Firebase 6.6.2 & rxjs 6.4.0